# Can't launch Enterprise build prepared with Xcode7

Tags: xcode7, code-signing-certificate, xcode7.1

Application crashes with following error (code signature invalid for)

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A363B6A-1B5E-455E-958D-AED4211572BF/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib:
>
> code signature invalid for
>
> '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A363B6A-1B5E-455E-958D-AED4211572BF/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code signing libs and Frameworks with the help of [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11284404/531877) helped to fix this issue.